# JavaScript lastIndexOf()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In C# I can do this

```
string ID = "ContentPlaceHolderDefault_MainSiteSectionArea_MyPagePlaceHolder_Item4_FavoritAmusementCalender_6_deleteRight_2";   
ID = ID.Substring(ID.LastIndexOf("_") + 1);
```

to return the last int `2`

How can I most easily do this in jQuery/JavaScript

The id is created dynamic and can for now be up to 3 digit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery isn't for string manipulation, but yes, the JavaScript language has `.indexOf()`, `.lastIndexOf()`, `.substr()`, `.substring()`, `.slice()` and other string methods. See [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org) for documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were close -- just case sensitive:

```
ID = ID.substring(ID.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GxXD9/)

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript also has a `lastIndexOf()` method, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp). You can therefore use:

```
var str1 = "Blah, blah, blah Calender_6_deleteRight_272";
var str2 = str1.substr (str1.lastIndexOf ("_") + 1);
```

This gives you `272`.

Keep in mind that, if the string *doesn't* contain an underscore, you'll get the original string back in its entirety. That may or may not be desired in your specific case - you can check the result of the `lastIndexOf()` call against `-1` to detect this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `str.substr(-1)`?

Comment: The ids is created dynamic and can for now be up to 3 digit? How can i easily get all after the last _

Comment: be careful IE does not like negative values.  You could use `str.substr(str.length-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with:

```
function get_last_part(str){
    var split = str.split('_');
    return split[split.length-1];
}
console.log(get_last_part("ContentPlaceHolderDefault_MainSiteSectionArea_MyPagePlaceHolder_Item4_FavoritAmusementCalender_6_deleteRight_2")); // this will write "2" in console
```

In this way you will get always result and you don't need to concern about out of index problems. This will return always last part of your string, if it doesn't have `_` you will get first part of it.

```
console.log(get_last_part("Content")); // will write "Content" into console
```